# Smarty object array access

Tags: php, loops, foreach, smarty

I have  result from a pdo object fetch all as std object result which iam goiing trough like this.

```
{foreach from=$users key=userID item=row}
                            <tr>  
                                <td>
                                    {$row->name}
                                </td>
                               {foreach from=$regions key=regionId item=region}
                                    <td>
                                    {assign var=id value=$row->id}{assign var=cid value=$region->id}  <input type="checkbox" name="regionChecked[{$region->id}][]" value="{$row->id}" {if $assighnedUsers.$id.$cid eq 1}checked="checked"{/if}>
                                    </td>



 {/foreach}
                                <td>
                                 {$row->id|@var_dump}   <input type="checkbox" name="regionDefault" value="{$row->id}" {if $loleq $row->id}checked="checked"{/if} >
                                </td>
                                <td data-user="{$userID}">
                                    {$deleteButton}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {/foreach}
```

Now my question is can i avoid the

```
{assign var=id value=$row->id}{assign var=cid value=$region->id}
```

Somehow? i tried varios combinations but none were working.

like $region.$row->id

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `->` use `.` and try

```
{assign var=id value=$row.id}{assign var=cid value=$region.id}
```

Comment: The above posted code works. i just want to avoid to even have to assign thouse values for  $assighnedUsers.$id.$cid i want to use somthing like this  $assighnedUsers.$row->id.$region->id